# Powershell: Secure Strings with Sysprep

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have two Powershell scripts I'm building for a Windows 7 image.  Prior to the image I run PRE-IMAGE.ps1, and it has a line like this in it:

```
$JoinDomainPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the password for $joinDomainUser" -AsSecureString
$strPass = $joinDomainPassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

I then save the the $strPass secure string to the registry, and run sysprep.

After a reboot with sysprep, the POST-IMAGE.ps1 then pulls $strPass from the registry, and has a line like this:

```
$strPass = $strPass | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($JoinDomainUser, $strPass)
```

However, these lines in POST-IMAGE.ps1 get the "Key not valid" error you'll see when you run convertto-securestring and convertfrom-securestring as different Windows users.  ([similiar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109958/saving-credentials-for-reuse-by-powershell-and-error-convertto-securestring-ke)) - but the catch here is I -AM- using the same user to convert to and from secure strings.  I'm guessing this has something to do with sysprep - but I can't wrap my head around it.

I apologize if this has been asked about before, I've found a few questions that touch on parts of this, but don't describe my EXACT problem.

Comment: Do you use the /generalise option with sysprep? If so, it will generate a new machine SID for the machine. Perhaps this is causing the issue?

Comment: Yup, I am using /generalize, but it's a requirement for the image I'm building.  I'm guessing that's what's screwing up the securestring key, too.  I've moved on to using the -key parameter in the interim until I can figure out a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Convert*-SecureString` cmdlets utilize the [Windows Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) to encrypt and decrypt strings.

By default, the encryption key composed for this kind of operation is specific to the user account that made the call, and the machine which the call was made to.

When you run `sysprep /generalize`, SysPrep (among other things) nukes the foundations of the local SAM database by generating a new machine SID and a new set of encryption keys.

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288348) explains how this affects EFS decryption, but your problem is essentially the same

Another way to think about it:
Since the Machine SID effectively represents the Logon Domain for local users, the user account is by definition NOT the same account as before you ran SysPrep.